# Insert lines in a file starting from a specific line

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to insert lines into a file in bash starting from a specific line.

Each line is a string which is an element of an array

```
line[0]="foo"
line[1]="bar"
...
```

and the specific line is 'fields'

```
file="$(cat $myfile)"
for p in $file; do
    if [ "$p" = 'fields' ]
        then insertlines()     #<- here
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

This can be done with sed: `sed 's/fields/fields\nNew Inserted Line/'`

```
$ cat file.txt 
line 1
line 2 
fields
line 3
another line 
fields
dkhs

$ sed 's/fields/fields\nNew Inserted Line/' file.txt 
line 1
line 2 
fields
New Inserted Line
line 3
another line 
fields
New Inserted Line
dkhs
```

Use `-i` to save in-place instead of printing to `stdout`

`sed -i 's/fields/fields\nNew Inserted Line/'`

As a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

match='fields'
insert='New Inserted Line'
file='file.txt'

sed -i "s/$match/$match\n$insert/" $file
```

Comment: When using `sed -i` does this rewrite the entire file but with `sed`'s replacements or is this similar to just opening up the file in a text editor and manually inserting the strings? I ask because I need to do this with a big file and having to write that much over and over again will take forever and wear out my SSDs and HDDs quicker.

Comment: What exactly do you expect a text editor to do physically if you open up a file, manually insert the strings and save it?

Comment: sed -i is not anymore working. On Solaris11.4 it throws "illegal option -i"

Answer (score 17):

Or anoter one example with the `sed`:

Prepare a `test.txt` file:

```
echo -e "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4" > /tmp/test.txt

cat /tmp/test.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

Add a new line into the `test.txt` file:

```
sed -i '2 a line 2.5' /tmp/test.txt
# sed for in-place editing (-i) of the file: 'LINE_NUMBER a-ppend TEXT_TO_ADD'

cat /tmp/test.txt
line 1
line 2
line 2.5
line 3
line 4
```

Answer (score 7):

This is definitely a case where you want to use something like `sed` (or `awk` or `perl`) rather than readling one line at a time in a shell loop.  This is not the sort of thing the shell does well or efficiently.

You might find it handy to write a reusable function.  Here's a simple one, though it won't work on fully-arbitrary text (slashes or regular expression metacharacters will confuse things):

```
function insertAfter # file line newText
{
   local file="$1" line="$2" newText="$3"
   sed -i -e "/^$line$/a"$'\\\n'"$newText"$'\n' "$file"
}
```

Example:

```
$ cat foo.txt
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party.
The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.
$ insertAfter foo.txt \
   "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party." \
   "The previous line is missing 'bjkquvxz.'"
$ cat foo.txt
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party.
The previous line is missing 'bjkquvxz.'
The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.
$
```

Answer (score -1):

sed is your friend:

```
:~$ cat text.txt 
foo
bar
baz
~$ 

~$ sed '/^bar/\na this is the new line/' text.txt > new_text.txt
~$ cat new_text.txt 
foo
bar
this is the new line
baz
~$
```

Comment: that won't work; you need a backslash and a newline in the sed command string after the `a`, not a space.