# Appending three new lines before the last line in a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, cat

I have this block of text in my sysctl.conf file.

```
#begin_atto_network_settings
net.inet.tcp.sendspace=1048576
net.inet.tcp.recvspace=1048576
net.inet.tcp.delayed_ack=0
net.inet.tcp.rfc1323=1
#end_atto_network_settings
```

I need to insert the following three lines before the #end_atto_network_settings.

```
kern.ipc.maxsockbuf=2097152    
net.link.generic.system.sndq_maxlen=512
net.classq.sfb.allocation=100
```

I'm assuming some variant of a sed command?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316437/insert-lines-in-a-file-starting-from-a-specific-line) ? It seems like your question has been asked before ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *edit* the file you can use `ed`, the standard editor:

```
ed -s file <<EOF
1,/#end_atto_network_settings/i
kern.ipc.maxsockbuf=2097152    
net.link.generic.system.sndq_maxlen=512
net.classq.sfb.allocation=100
.
w
q
EOF
```

Note that *editing* the file will not change the permissions and preserve symlinks; `sed -i` typically creates a temporary file, removes the old file and renames the temporary file: so it doesn't preserve permissions and symlinks.

Comment: Perfect! Also, great to know as I do need to preserve permissions, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to insert lines before the pattern:

```
sed '/end_atto_network_settings/i \
kern.ipc.maxsockbuf=2097152 \
net.link.generic.system.sndq_maxlen=512 \
net.classq.sfb.allocation=100' file
```

Or if your file doesn't have blank lines at EOF:

```
sed '$ i\
kern.ipc.maxsockbuf=2097152 \
net.link.generic.system.sndq_maxlen=512 \
net.classq.sfb.allocation=100' file
```

Meaning:
`$` - end of file,
`i` - insert,
 `\` - new line separator